Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Felt I had to skip a couple of the questions in the queue as I'd answered them...

Final Results

Large Lego Minifig Styles

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Which bricks warrant an extra to be included in a set?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Part Identification - bricks with posts

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


How does cleaning yellowed Lego bricks affect their clutch power?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the input to the Speed Regulator?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Retrobrite cleaning on old cellulose acetate bricks?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Cost of different works in a LEGO set price?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Why do some sets contain parts of an unrelated colour?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Small lego train sets on narrow gauge track?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Where can I download the EV3 education edition software for free?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

